# How to sort 2D array by single row in Perl?

Tags: perl

I have 2D array:

`my @array = ([3,4,1,2], [Black,Orange,White,Blue]);`

I need to sort it by first row, so expected result is

```
1,2,3,4
White, Blue, Black, Orange
```

Is there any quick way to do that in perl?
I know how to sort each row separately, but this is not the goal.

Comment: Could you clarify what your Perl code actually looks like? How is your array initialized for instance? What you show us isn't a 2D array, it's two separate arrayref.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by a 2D array in Perl.
From the notation in your question, there are 2 separate array references:

```perl
$array_ref1 = [3, 4, 1, 2];
$array_ref2 = ['Black', 'Orange', 'White', 'Blue'];
```

A 2D array could be one of these:

```perl
@array_of_arrayrefs = ([3, 'Black'], [4, 'Orange'], [1, 'White'], [2, 'Blue']);
%hash = (3 => 'Black', 4 => 'Orange', 1 => 'White', 2 => 'Blue');
```

In most cases, I would recommend using hashes if possible - you can read a bit about them here: [Hashes in Perl](https://perlmaven.com/perl-hashes)

You can use the [sort function](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) for arrays

```perl
# for array_of_arrayrefs
my @sorted_array = sort { $a[0] <=> $b[0] } @array_of_arrayrefs;
```

As hash is an un-ordered group of key-value pairs, just call [keys function](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html) and sort the result array (using it to call the hash value as needed).

Answer (score 0):

If you have associated keys and values, then I'd say first you want to transpose the array into a hash:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings; 

use Data::Dumper;

my @array = ([3,4,1,2], ["Black","Orange","White","Blue"]);

my %mapping;
#Assign 'first array' as keys, and second array as values. 
@mapping{@{$array[0]}} = @{$array[1]};


#for debugging
print Dumper \%mapping; 

my @sorted_keys = sort keys %mapping;

print join (",", @sorted_keys),"\n"; 
print join (",", @mapping{@sorted_keys} ),"\n";
```

I've gone for a trivial case with the hash-slice assignment, but it allows you to perform arbitrary sorts and maintain the key-value relationship.

You could also adapt this for multi-row input, preserving the column-relationship, although it does get a bit more complicated you can't use a hash-slice assignment like I did any more, but you can build each row into key-value pairs, and either print-as-you-go or merge them to make just one hash of columnated values.